# Difference between using loc and not using it in dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Titanic Tutorial, it provides this line of code to explore the pattern:

```
women = train_data.loc[train_data.Sex == 'female']["Survived"]
```

But what is the difference between the second line of code and what is the reason for using the first line of code?

```
women = train_data[train_data.Sex == 'female']["Survived"]
```

It seems like both of the codes provide the same outputs.

Comment: Even though you might get the same result in your case, Pandas recommends using `.loc` for accessing a group of rows and columns by labels or booleans arrays.

Comment: got it, thank you!

Comment: BTW, I believe that the correct syntax in that case should be `women = train_data.loc[train_data.Sex == 'female', "Survived"]`, where you accessed the survived column on the condition of being female

Comment: I actually got that code from kaggle tutorial. But thank you I learned something new :)

Comment: Cool, it's probably outdated. Good luck!

Comment: The syntax is correct because `"Survived"` is another column. The code first filters the rows based on the condition `train_data.loc[train_data.Sex == 'female']` i.e, to get all the rows where the sex is female. It then retrieves data from the `"Survived"` column and saves it in women. So, the variable women contains the series of values from the `"Survived"` column of only females.